# How to close SFSafariViewController automatically when reaching a certain page

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

I want to close SFSafariViewController automatically upon reaching the "thank you" page of the Dropbox site after the user uploads something; it needs to automatically dismiss. How can I do that?

Here is what I have so far:

```
@IBAction func Singles5(_ sender: Any) {
    let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: NSURL(string: "https://www.dropbox/Upload")! as URL)
    self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    safariVC.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Up-voted question. Now, do you have **any** examples where this is possible? (I haven't used SFSafariViewController in anything - personal or professional - since Swift 2. Can this be done?)

Comment: I did Answer That
Check My Answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62280728/9403403)

Answer (score 4):

One way I can think of is using the **Custom URL scheme**. You can specify your app's custom URL in the **callback** parameter of Dropbox (if Dropbox has callback). So when the user has finished uploading his/her file, dropbox executes the callback. In this case your app will receive the callback, with any parameters have you specified. This will call the function `application(app, open, options)->Bool` in your `AppDelegate`. Now, you can use a reference to the *ViewController* which presents the `SFSafariViewController` and call `SafariViewController.dissmissViewController()`.